# How do I store a pickerview selection in a variable?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipickerview

Why isn't this storing the `pickerView` selection into the property of my mainMatrix object?

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    [mainMatrix setM:[[self.numbers objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]] intValue]];
    [mainMatrix setN:[[self.numbers objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]] intValue]];
}
```

Comment: check that `[self.numbers objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]` is actually returning the proper value

Comment: u need to use this code on action of any done button for ur selected values from pickerView...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split your code up so you can actually see what is going on:

```
NSUInteger selectedRow = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
int num = [self.numbers[selectedRow] intValue];
[mainMatrix setM:num];

selectedRow = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1];
int num = [self.numbers[selectedRow] intValue];
[mainMatrix setN:num];
```

Now you can debug the code and see what is actually happening. Readable, debuggable code is much better than cramming it all onto one line.

Make sure that `mainMatrix` is non-nil at this point in the code. Also make sure `self.numbers` is non-nil. And last (really first), make sure you have set the `delegate` on the picker view.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a same array to populate both components in pickerview ?? if yes then try this code.

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(component == 0) {
          [mainMatrix setM:[[self.numbers objectAtIndex:row] intValue]];
      }else if(component == 1){
          [mainMatrix setN:[[self.numbers objectAtIndex:row] intValue]];
      }
}
```